# How to add custom heading and make full width PDF using Data Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a data table which is populated using a database.

I am using the following script to generate pdf from data table. It works fine but I want to use my custom heading at the top of the table and make the table full width and landscape orientation.

Here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#user-table').DataTable( {

        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [

            'copyHtml5',

            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );

    </script>
```

Need help

Comment: Have u tried httpHeaders?

Comment: no i'm novice user of PHP i don't have idea to use httpHeaders

Comment: can u post detailed code

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41263/add-fixed-header-and-footer-to-exported-pdf-file) is the example of adding customize header and footer in Data Table.